# Hover effect on SVG fails if I style the polyline

Tags: html, css, svg

I´ve a strange hover behaviour if I want to fill a polyline.

```css
.two:hover {
  fill: red !important;
}

.one:hover {
  fill: red !important;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 4169.1 3129.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
        <polyline class="one" style="fill:none;stroke:#E67E5C;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="
        1656.8,1707.9 1511.2,1657.3 1504.5,1676.9 1337.9,1619.1 1344.7,1599.7 1352.7,1576.3 1366.2,1537.5 1428.9,1472.7 1428.1,1471.9
        1451.8,1447.4 1484.1,1458.4 1483.8,1459.5 1684.8,1529.5 1684,1579.3 1689.7,1581.4 1683.7,1598.4 1683.2,1631.7 1656.8,1707.9
        "/>
        <polyline class="two" points="
        1343,1398.7 1311,1443.1 1313.7,1445 1299.2,1465.2 1296.5,1463.3 1264.7,1507.4 996.4,1314.7 1028.2,1270.6 1025.5,1268.7
        1040,1248.2 1043,1250.4 1074.5,1206 1343,1398.7"/>
        
    </svg>
```

So I created a custom styling for the first polyline. The second one has no styling. I apply a hover effect on both. The second object with no styling is working as expected, but the first on not. I have to move the mouse exactly over the stroke-line to get the polyline filled.
Whats the problem with it?

I prepared a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxpe8yaf/) for you.

Comment: `fill:none` might be the problem.

Comment: and why? The inital polylines should be transparent. The svg-code above is the exact output from Adoble Illustrator.

Comment: I would be a little sceptical about the svg output from Illustrator. It tends to be full of gunk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trigger the `:hover` for the full area of a polyline, you need to add him the `pointer-events: all;` css rule:

```css
.one {
  pointer-events: all;
}

.two:hover {
  fill: red !important;
}

.one:hover {
  fill: red !important;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 4169.1 3129.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polyline class="one" style="fill:none;stroke:#E67E5C;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="
    1656.8,1707.9 1511.2,1657.3 1504.5,1676.9 1337.9,1619.1 1344.7,1599.7 1352.7,1576.3 1366.2,1537.5 1428.9,1472.7 1428.1,1471.9
    1451.8,1447.4 1484.1,1458.4 1483.8,1459.5 1684.8,1529.5 1684,1579.3 1689.7,1581.4 1683.7,1598.4 1683.2,1631.7 1656.8,1707.9
    " />
  <polyline class="two" points="
    1343,1398.7 1311,1443.1 1313.7,1445 1299.2,1465.2 1296.5,1463.3 1264.7,1507.4 996.4,1314.7 1028.2,1270.6 1025.5,1268.7
    1040,1248.2 1043,1250.4 1074.5,1206 1343,1398.7" />

</svg>
```